# How do i get Archived files list on specific record?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, soql, contentdocument, archive

One of my requirement is to list out all archived files on specific record so i have created one lightning component and i did following SOQL to get all archived files on specific record but it's not giving me any result.

Can anyone help me to sort this out ?

```
Select Id, Title from ContentDocument where ParentId =: recordId AND isArchived = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ALL rows for querying archived records

```
ContentDocument[] cd=[SELECT Id, Title FROM ContentDocument where isArchived = true  ALL ROWS];
system.debug([SELECT id   FROM ContentDocumentLink where ContentDocumentId=:cd[0].id and LinkedEntityId='0060o00001ChnVeAAJ' ALL ROWS]);
```

you have to do something like this

Comment: Using this query i can get all archived files, not the one which is related to specific record.

Comment: what happened when you add your filter where ParentId =: recordId and isArchived = true

Comment: `Aggregations:0|SELECT Id, Title FROM ContentDocument WHERE (ParentId = 'a01C000000r94WxIAI' AND isArchived = TRUE) ALL ROWS

ROWS:0`

Comment: there is no field like parentId you have to use ContentDocument and linkedentityid i have edited the code